# How to save the image captured using Camera and save in another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to save the image captured using Camera and save in another ViewController ?

I am making a Photo Gallery App. But i dont know how to save the Captured image and show it in collection view in another viewcontroller. Currently i am using UIImagePickerController to access iphone camera and library .Can anyone help me to do that.

Here is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: You want to capture image from Class A and after image got selected, want to show in another class B, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

  // Save image
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

  [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by adding NSNotificationcenter.

**Class A** - *Where you select the image from camera*

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
     UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"GotNewImage" object: chosenImage];
}
```

**Class B** - Where you want to pass image after selection and show on collection view. Add Nsnotificationcenter for this class in Viewdidload

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(GotNewImage:) name:@"GotNewImage" object:nil];
```

//To get the image on Class B

```
-(void)GotNewImage:(NSNotification*)notification
 {
     UIImage * newImage = (UIImage*) notification.object;
     //Now do whatever you want to do with your image...
     //Add in collection view and reload the collection view
 }
```